# What is a good resource to find out about making custom walkers?

Tags: walker

Custom walkers seem to be a poorly-documented area of WP. Online tutorials focus on styling the output, not on directing the walker to go where you want it.

I am reading the code, but I wonder if there's a good resource I'm missing. If you know about walkers, how and where did you learn about them?

Comment: I learned how to do a huge amount mainly by reading the code base. There were some articles I started with and then quickly realised how much more I could do with them. Is there something in particular you're hoping to achieve?

Comment: In the past I attempted to build a menu from taxonomies, which resulted in my asking this question: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/34011/how-do-i-dynamically-populate-wp-nav-menu-from-a-custom-taxonomy. I've made some progress since then. But I could definitely benefit from a good book or an article.

Comment: you're right that part is poorly documented. i've looked at source and it isn't really that revelatory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I stumbled across [this article](http://www.kriesi.at/archives/improve-your-wordpress-navigation-menu-output), I think it could be of tremendous use to you. It helped me understand it a lot better.

I believe there was a question on here in which (I think) @Rarst answered that linked to it, but I can't seem to find it. If someone can find it and edit my answer in place of this that would be great!

**EDIT**: Found another pretty good resource you can [find here](http://phpdoc.wordpress.org/trunk/WordPress/Walker.html).

**EDIT**: More excellent resources below you can look through. I made the ones that are extremely useful in my opinion **bold**!

- **http://resources.mdbitz.com/2010/08/creating-a-wordpress-custom-page-walker**

  This one in my opinion is the best explanation to modifying the output of the items. It actually also explains what each of the Walker Class functions do.
- http://wpti.ps/functions/extending-wordpress-walker-class/

  This one was a result of the first link, as you can see they link to the first article in this article. :)
- **[http://www.jeangalea.com/wordpress/how-to-use-wordpress-walker-classes](http://www.jeangalea.com/wordpress/how-to-use-wordpress-walker-classes/)**

  This has some that I posted above as well as like 5-6 other articles on extending the Walker Class.

Comment: +1. Thank you. This goes some way to answering the question of how to make the per-post output richer. But it doesn't touch on how the walker chooses which posts to get its material from, so I cannot accept it as the answer to the above Q.

Comment: @djb No problem, I am also interested in learning more about the Walker Class and I am more than happy to help/brainstorm. I'm going to continuously update this answer with more articles and resources for future visitors. I added some more above if you didn't see yet! :)